# how can I solve strictFunctionTypes errors for generic handlers?

Tags: typescript

we have built a pipeline for processing data from a MongoDB collection in TypeScript.

Each document within a collection has a `type` property which we use to discriminate. We then send each document through a *processor*.

Below is the contrived/simplified version of our code:

```
type Processor = (input: BaseInput) => BaseOutput;

// base
interface BaseInput {
    name: string;
}

interface BaseOutput {
    id: number;
}

// one
interface InputOne extends BaseInput {
    title: string;
}

interface OutputOne extends BaseOutput {
    fullname: string;
}

// two
interface InputTwo extends BaseInput {
    age: number;
}

interface OutputTwo extends BaseOutput {
    parent: string;
}

const mapping = new Map<string, Processor>([
    ['one', processorOne],
    ['two', processorTwo],
]);

function processorOne(input: InputOne): OutputOne {
    return {
        id: 1,
        fullname: input.title + input.name,
    }
}

function processorTwo(input: InputTwo): OutputTwo {
    return {
        id: 2,
        parent: input.name,
    }
}
```

This is working fine in `2.5`, but we're getting errors in `2.6` with `strictFunctionTypes` for the `mapping`:

```
Argument of type '([string, (input: InputOne) => OutputOne] | [string, (input: InputTwo) => OutputTwo])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, Processor][]'.
  Type '[string, (input: InputOne) => OutputOne] | [string, (input: InputTwo) => OutputTwo]' is not assignable to type '[string, Processor]'.
    Type '[string, (input: InputOne) => OutputOne]' is not assignable to type '[string, Processor]'.
      Type '(input: InputOne) => OutputOne' is not assignable to type 'Processor'.
        Types of parameters 'input' and 'input' are incompatible.
          Type 'BaseInput' is not assignable to type 'InputOne'.
            Property 'title' is missing in type 'BaseInput'.
```

I understand why it is warning me, but **how can we tweak the declaration (or implementation) to be type safe?**

Comment: Are you asking how to make this code typecheck as-is (without changing the runtime behavior), or how to make the entire code *actually* safe against incorrect calls?

Comment: Good question. I guess my first question should be: am I just wrong in writing this kind of code?
If the answer is that I am not completely crazy, then how do I make the compiler happy with `strictFunctionTypes`?

Answer (score 3):

Other answers about type assertions are good, if you're comfortable with telling the compiler not to worry about parameter contravariance.  If you want the compiler to actually help you use these things in a type-safe manner, though, you need to explicitly define the key for the `mapping` and how it relates to the exact input and output types for the `Processor` in question.  Here we go:

First, let's make `Processor` generic so you can express exactly what type of `Processor` you're using:

```
type Processor<I extends BaseInput=BaseInput, O extends BaseOutput=BaseOutput>
  = (input: I) => O;
```

So a plain `Processor` is just the same as it used to be, but now you can talk specifically about `Processor<InputOne, OutputOne>` as a processor that takes an `InputOne` as an input and produces and `OutputOne` as an output.

Now let's describe the type of the things you're going to store in `mapping`:

```
interface ProcessorTypeMappings {
  one: { input: InputOne, output: OutputOne };
  two: { input: InputTwo, output: OutputTwo };
}
```

This is a bit verbose (and causes more verbosity later) but it helps if you need to query, say, just the input type for `mapping.get('two')`, for some function later.  In any case you can add properties above for more processors.

We can use `ProcessorTypeMappings` to describe the functionality of `mapping` more accurately.  I'm only going to specify `get()` and `set()`... this isn't perfect but you can tweak it as you see fit:

```
interface ProcessorMap extends Map<string, Processor<any, any>> {
  get<K extends keyof ProcessorTypeMappings>(key: K):
    Processor<ProcessorTypeMappings[K]['input'], ProcessorTypeMappings[K]['output']>;
  set<K extends keyof ProcessorTypeMappings>(key: K,
    val: Processor<ProcessorTypeMappings[K]['input'], ProcessorTypeMappings[K]['output']>): this;
}
```

So `get()` takes a key from `ProcessorTypeMappings`, and produces a value which is a `Processor<I,O>` where `I` is the `input` property of the relevant property in `ProcessorTypeMappings`, and `O` is the corresponding `output` property.  And `set()` is similar, except that it takes both a key and a value.

Now, finally, you can create `mapping` as a `ProcessorMap` and populate it:

```
const mapping: ProcessorMap = new Map<string, any>();
mapping.set('one', processorOne);  // okay
mapping.set('two', processorTwo);  // okay
```

Those type-check fine.  I did that using `set()` instead of using constructor arguments, which would have been a little more annoying to get done (since the constructor is its own type).

And, you will get type safety when you use `mapping` later:

```
declare const inputOne: InputOne;
declare const inputTwo: InputTwo;
const outputOne = mapping.get('one')(inputOne); // OutputOne
const oops = mapping.get('three'); // no such key
const nope = mapping.get('two')(inputOne); // InputOne not assignable to InputTwo
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20Processor%3CI%20extends%20BaseInput%3DBaseInput%2C%20O%20extends%20BaseOutput%3DBaseOutput%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3D%20%28input%3A%20I%29%20%3D%3E%20O%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20base%0D%0Ainterface%20BaseInput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20BaseOutput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20one%0D%0Ainterface%20InputOne%20extends%20BaseInput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20OutputOne%20extends%20BaseOutput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20fullname%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20two%0D%0Ainterface%20InputTwo%20extends%20BaseInput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20OutputTwo%20extends%20BaseOutput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20parent%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20processorOne%28input%3A%20InputOne%29%3A%20OutputOne%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fullname%3A%20input.title%20%2B%20input.name%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20processorTwo%28input%3A%20InputTwo%29%3A%20OutputTwo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20parent%3A%20input.name%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ProcessorTypeMappings%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20one%3A%20%7B%20input%3A%20InputOne%2C%20output%3A%20OutputOne%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20two%3A%20%7B%20input%3A%20InputTwo%2C%20output%3A%20OutputTwo%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ProcessorMap%20extends%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20Processor%3Cany%2C%20any%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20get%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20ProcessorTypeMappings%3E%28key%3A%20K%29%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Processor%3CProcessorTypeMappings%5BK%5D%5B%27input%27%5D%2C%20ProcessorTypeMappings%5BK%5D%5B%27output%27%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20set%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20ProcessorTypeMappings%3E%28key%3A%20K%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20val%3A%20Processor%3CProcessorTypeMappings%5BK%5D%5B%27input%27%5D%2C%20ProcessorTypeMappings%5BK%5D%5B%27output%27%5D%3E%29%3A%20this%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20mapping%3A%20ProcessorMap%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20any%3E%28%29%3B%0D%0Amapping.set%28%27one%27%2C%20processorOne%29%3B%0D%0Amapping.set%28%27two%27%2C%20processorTwo%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20inputOne%3A%20InputOne%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20inputTwo%3A%20InputTwo%3B%0D%0Aconst%20outputOne%20%3D%20mapping.get%28%27one%27%29%28inputOne%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20OutputOne%0D%0Aconst%20oops%20%3D%20mapping.get%28%27three%27%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20no%20such%20key%0D%0Aconst%20nope%20%3D%20mapping.get%28%27two%27%29%28inputOne%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20InputOne%20not%20assignable%20to%20InputTwo%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Hope that helps; good luck!

---

### UPDATE

It occurred to me (and this is *blindingly obvious* in retrospect) that if you really have just a simple mapping from string-valued keys to particular processor types, then you may want to use a plain old regular *object* instead of any kind of `Map`.  String-valued keys and differently-typed-values are what objects do best.  And TypeScript will helpfully infer a fairly specific type for such an object, so you don't even need to declare a mess of interfaces or types:

Here's your `mapping`:

```
const mapping = {
  one: processorOne,
  two: processorTwo
};
```

That's it.  And testing it:

```
declare const inputOne: InputOne;
declare const inputTwo: InputTwo;
const outputOne = mapping.one(inputOne); // OutputOne
const oops = mapping.three; // no such key
const nope = mapping.two(inputOne); // InputOne not assignable to InputTwo
```

Insanely simple.  You may decide your use case is complicated enough to require the heavier machinery above; that's up to you.  But simpler is often better, so I wanted to make sure to present it.

Okay, good luck again!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. You are right, it is quite verbose for what I thought was a simple use case. But it seems to do the trick. I will look into implementing this and will make sure to come back on mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is not wrong about the fact it can't prove that the assignment `processorOne` to `Processor` is safe. You say you "know" based on a type property that you need to pass `InputOne` to `processorOne` even though the argument to `Process` is of type `BaseInput`.

The simplest solution for when we "know" something the compiler does not know is to use a type assertion:

```
const mapping = new Map<string, Processor>([
    ['one', <Processor>processorOne],
    ['two', <Processor>processorTwo],
]);
```

The safer solution would be to make `Processor` generic and use a custom map that knows about the generic arguments to `Processor`. But here you are basically pushing the assertions to the map and forging your consumers to specify the type arguments which is not ideal.

```
class ProcessorMap {
  private innerMap = new Map<string, any>() ;
  set<TIn extends BaseInput, TOut extends BaseOutput>(key: string, processor: Processor<TIn, TOut>) {
    this.innerMap.set(key, <any>processor);
    return this;
  }
  get<TIn extends BaseInput, TOut extends BaseOutput>(key: string) {
    return this.innerMap.get(key);
  }
}

const mapping = new ProcessorMap()
    .set('one', processorOne)
    .set('two', processorTwo);
```